# MemoryStream Bug When Upload the Dropbox

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, dropbox

```cs
var filePath = startupPath + "\\" + $"test-{house.Id}.png";
var oAuthResponse = await MakeRequestAsync();
DropboxClient dbx = new DropboxClient(oAuthResponse.access_token);
var folder = "/Apps/MyFiles";
var file = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.png";
var fileToUpload = @$"{filePath}";
using (var mem = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fileToUpload)))
{
    var updated = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(
        folder + "/" + file,
        Dropbox.Api.Files.WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance,
        body: mem);

    var urlHelper = await dbx.Files.GetTemporaryLinkAsync(updated.PathDisplay);
    house.MainImage = urlHelper.Link;
    db.Estates.Update(house);
    db.SaveChanges();
    Console.WriteLine("Dropboxa");
}
```

After this line:

```cs
DropboxClient dbx = new DropboxClient(oAuthResponse.access_token);
```

Debug cursor return the first line. So Application Started again but i dont get any exceptions.

This is Other method

```cs
public static async Task<OAuthResponse> MakeRequestAsync()
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        // URL and API credentials
        string url = "https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/token";
        string clientId = "My_Key";
        string clientSecret = "My_Client_Secret";

        // Add basic authentication
        var byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{clientId}:{clientSecret}");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

        // Set up form data
        var formData = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "grant_type", "refresh_token" },
            { "refresh_token", "My_Token" }
        };

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData));

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // Deserialize the JSON response into an OAuthResponse object
                OAuthResponse oauthResponse = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<OAuthResponse>(content)!;

                Console.WriteLine("Access Token: " + oauthResponse.access_token);
                Console.WriteLine("Token Type: " + oauthResponse.token_type);
                Console.WriteLine("Expires In: " + oauthResponse.expires_in);

                return oauthResponse;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Message}");
        }
        return new OAuthResponse();
    }
}
```

I think this bug For the MakeRequestAsync method. Because this is async method. But i cant change method async -> sync. This is C# Console App.

Comment: Are you awaiting the method that calls the `MakeRequestAsync` method?

Comment: You don't need to use `MemoryStream` at all here - just open a `FileStream` on the file (_without_ loading the file into-memory, there's no reason for doing that here, so you're just being inefficient) and pass that `FileStream` to `UploadAsync`.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama yes. And first block code is in the async method too.

Comment: @Dai Can you write the true variant ?

Comment: @ShahinBabayev "true variant"?

Comment: @Dai i change (MemoryStream ->  FileStream) but the same problem continues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason since this is a console app is that your main method is [not async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line). Your console process will terminate when the "main" thread reaches the end of the main method, and this is likely before all async tasks has completed.

Change your main method signature to something like

```
public static async Task Main() {

    await ...
}
```

and make sure all tasks are awaited, and you are not using any async void methods.

Comment: Perfect ! Now everything is normal. Thanks for the reply.